# Конструкция "Вот это (что-то) так (что-то)"

Tags: пунктуация

> Вот это игра так игра..

Нужны ли тут запятые или тире? Почему?

Comment: Мне не совсем ясно, что не так с вопросом. Можно хотя бы в комментариях посоветовать как мне видоизменить вопрос, чтобы он соответствовал нормам сайта? Спасибо.

Comment: Mihail строго говоря этот вопрос подпадает под "Questions about spelling, stress, pronunciation, and other information easily available in a dictionary are off-topic, unless prior research effort is indicated. We are a Q&A site, not a reference dictionary."

Я думаю, это и причина даунвоутов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4. Запятая не ставится:

1) между двумя повторяющимися словами, из которых второе употреблено с отрицанием не, если сочетание этих слов образует единое смысловое целое, выражающее неполное отрицание или неопределенность в обозначении чего-либо: Страшно не страшно, а на душе как-то строго (Леск.); Дождь не дождь, а паши (Ш.); На нём надето что-то круглое: сюртук не сюртук, пальто не пальто, фрак не фрак, а что-то среднее (С.-Щ.); Рад не рад, корми его (П.); Попал в стаю, лай не лай, а хвостом виляй (Ч.); Маленький не маленький, а это знать не мешает; Была не была — пойду;

2) при повторении слова с частицей **так** для усиления смысла: Пропаду так пропаду, всё равно! (Дост.); Свадьба так свадьба; я Огудалова, я нищенства не допущу (Остр.); Вот это была косьба так косьба! (См.); Да так да, нет так нет; Не надо так не надо.

Розенталь Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация. § 16.